# how to start post request by clicking table row

Tags: jquery, post, html-table, ejs

I am using EJS on the front-end, and I have a table as follows:

```
<tbody>
<% for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {  %>
   <tr>
      <td>
         a
      </td>
      <td>
         b
      </td>
      <td>
         c
      </td>
   </tr>
<% } %>
</tbody>
```

length is a variable passed from the backend. I wish to start a post requests by clicking the rows (any cell within the row should be clickable), and in the post request I need to send data about the value of i for that row. Would anyone have any suggestions on the most appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To attach an event handler in jQuery use the [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on) and attach it to the `tr` element. To send a POST request use [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) or [`$.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post). Given that the `i` variable matches the `index()` of the row within the parent `table`, you can use that in place of the server side `i` value.

With all that said, the code would look like this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('table tr').on('click', e => {
    $.post('URL-here', {
      index: $(e.target).index()
    }, function(response) {
      console.log(response); // response is the data sent back from the server
    });
  });
});
```